# apt-add-repository: Command not found

Tags: apt, add-apt-repository

If I try something like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

it raises an error: Command not found.

So I installed the repository with:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

and it installed, however it still gives me

```
 apt-add-repository: Command not found
```

also it does not help to install python, tried that as well.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show?  `apt-add-repository` should be in the `/usr/bin` folder.

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin                                                                              Do not know what to make of this through.

Comment: OK, so the path has it there.  Make sure the file is in that folder then.  `ls -al /usr/bin/apt-add-repository`  And that one should be a link that points to `add-apt-repository` that should be in the same folder.

Comment: It does point to add-apt-repository

Comment: Does `ls -al /usr/bin/add-apt-repository` then show an existing file?

Comment: I think so it says 'irwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May 8 16:58 /usr/bin/apt-add-repository --> add-apt-repository'

Comment: Try the second command I sent.  I am looking to see if `add-apt-repository` is there.

Comment: The last command you sent did not point to anything output is:               /usr/bin/add-apt-repository

Comment: That's the problem.  Try `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-common`

Comment: You. Are a god. Thank you so much. So if I understand it right, the add-apt-repository was installed in a wrong folder?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it wasn't where it was supposed to be.  Glad you got it fixed.  I will write up that last command as an answer for you.  =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The application `add-apt-repository` is not in the `/usr/bin` folder where it needs to be thus causing `apt-add-repository` to fail since it is a link file.

```
ls -al /usr/bin/apt-add-repository 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May  8  2017 /usr/bin/apt-add-repository -> add-apt-repository
```

Run the following command to reinstall the software properties to reinstall the `add-apt-repository` application:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-common
```

Now the file `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` should exist and the commands should work now.

Comment: I think the real reason for OP's problem was a simple typo: `apt-add-repository: Command not found`. `add-apt-....` or `apt-add-....`

Comment: @mook765 Both exist on my system.  `apt-add-repository` is linked to `add-apt-repository` and they do this for mistyping or backwards compatibility like `egrep` is aliased to `grep -E`.  There are no needs for them, but they sure help people.

Comment: Wow, they both exist in my system too, didn't know that, one point for you...