# Unable to locate package iperf

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-sources

I tried to install iperf on ubuntu focal version, but I am unable. I updated the package and deleted the /etc/apt/sources.list, I recovered it back. But still getting the same error unable to locate the package.

Thanks help is highly appreciated.

Comment: is Universe enabled on your system?  `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and then `sudo apt update && sudo apt install iperf` should do it.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWard, I run the command sudo add-apt-respository universe, it says command not found

Comment: If you cannot `add-apt-repository`, then a package is missing. Do this in your terminal: `sudo apt install software-properties-common`. Then you can `sudo apt update`. Then you can `sudo add-apt-repository universe`.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful support @Matigo, I tried but still getting command not found

Comment: If you do not have `apt` on your system, then you may not be running Ubuntu. Your initial statement said you were running Focal, which is 20.04, so you should have `apt` on your system unless you've intentionally broken something.

Comment: If you are using a desktop version, go to Software and Updates / Ubuntu Software tab and tick the box beside "Community-maintained...(universe)  Also, you mistyped the command "add-apt-**respository** universe" which is why it didn't work.

Comment: @Matigo, i think the file is corrupted or misconfigured that's why I am facing this issue

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I am not using desktop version its server version.Thanks

Comment: You might want to see https://askubuntu.com/a/1044600/231142 to fix the `add-apt-repository` or `apt-add-repository` commands.

Comment: @Terrance, Thanks I checked this and tried I am retrieving cannot access /usr/bin/apt-add repository no such file or directory. Also I have VM assigned on my university cluster.

Comment: @goharluck Did you run just the `apt install` command or the `apt install --reinstall` command?  There is a difference.  Just the `install` by itself will not fix it if it detects part of the application already installed.

Comment: @Terrance, I followed exactly the same steps apt install --reinstall. Thanks

Comment: From above you have a misspelling in the command.  Try doing it this way, type in `sudo add-apt` then press the Tab key twice to complete the command.  From what I am reading above you typed in **respository** and not **repository**.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for your wonderful support it's now working like a charm. Thank you all Matigo,OrganicMarble,ThomasWard for helping to sort out this issue